# How do i manage the SQL Server connections in asp.net core MVC mode?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a APP's server program which using asp.net core MVC mode. And in the XXXXcontrller i never use code like "Connection.open()" and "Connection.close()",a HTTP GET action is like this.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> register(string phoneNum, string password, string userType)
    {
        //从数据库里找到m.Id和 id相同的车，赋给dbCars
        var dbCars = await _context.dbUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName == phoneNum);
        // var dbCars= _context.dbCars.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault<dbCars>();
        if (dbCars == null)//如果为空，则注册 
        {
            //注册新用户
            dbCars = new dbUsers();
            dbCars.UserName = phoneNum;
            dbCars.Password = password;
            dbCars.UserType = userType;
            dbCars.IsVerified = true;
            _context.Add(dbCars);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //注册完成之后，把ID、用户类型和是否认证返回回去
            List<string> userInfo = new List<string>();
            userInfo.Add(dbCars.Id.ToString().Trim());
            userInfo.Add(dbCars.UserType.ToString().Trim());
            userInfo.Add(dbCars.IsVerified.ToString());
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo);
            return Ok(json);
        }
        else //如果不为空就代表注册过了
        {
            return Ok("0"); //返回1代表注册过了
        }
    }
```

I wondered how should i maintain the SQL Connections when many users access this service?? Should I close these connections manually? Or it can be done automatically by some magic?? If many users access this service, do my program breaked down??

I am confused, who can give me an answer??

Comment: I think you are using Entity Framework. In EF opening and closing a connection is managed by itself, so you don't need to be bother about that.

Comment: Yes, it it Entity Framework. So, how many users can access my server is depend on what?? on IIS SETTING? on SQL SERVER SETTING? It is nothing to do with my Server? Here is my Connection String  " "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Database=nxts;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true""

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Entity Framework or ORM you should see and set the connection string on the web.config or if it's on a separate layer you can see the settings on the app.config. If you run the application it will use the startup project of your application connectionstring app.config(windows application) or web.config (web application)

Comment: Yes, the connection string is alright, and my app can run. I just wonder should i control the connections(open and close) and how? or should i left it behind.